# How can I trace the downtime reported by Newrelic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic, torquebox, newrelic-platform, downtime

I am getting downtime alert for web application with different failure messages.
these all are 2-3 mins downtime. This downtime is random 2-3 times in a day.

**failure messages**

- problem parsing the HTTP response, no further detail available.
- connection error (Connection refused)
- timeout after 30 seconds
- 404 status

Application info

```
Ruby on Rails 3.2.14
running torquebox server with jruby [ http://torquebox.org/ ]
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392)
```

**how can I trace the problem of these downtime, so that I can get where is the issue**

Comment: Downtime can have multiple reason but investigating error logs would definitely help. Since NewRelic analyses only server side performance it all should be clearly laid out in logs.

Comment: New Relic Support can also try running these requests manually and offering more detail about the nature of these errors. You might also want to look into raising the threshold for downtime alerts as these look like a pretty random spread of very brief errors.